# Kernel of Quadratic Field Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $D > 0$ be squarefree and consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. Then the field norm $N : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) \to \mathbb{Q}^\times$ is given by $N(a + b\sqrt{D}) = a^2 - D b^2$. Let $K$ be the kernel of this map, consisting of elements of norm $+1$. I'm looking for an example where $K$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \bigoplus_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups.

The motivation is the [Pell conic group](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.391.5845&rep=rep1&type=pdf) $C$ defined on the curve $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$. If $D$ is a square of a rational number, then $x \mapsto (\frac{x+x^{-1}}{2},\frac{x-x^{-1}}{2\sqrt{D}})$ gives an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^{\times} \cong C$, but otherwise we have the isomorphism $K \cong C$ where $K$ is the kernel of the norm map. I am wondering whether the group structure of $C$ alone can detect the irrationality of a square root of a natural number. Below I've included my current thoughts on this question.

Let's consider $D = 2$. Then the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is generated by powers of $\pm(1 + \sqrt{2})$, so it is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a UFD, we have that any element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^\times$ can be written as a unique product of primes and units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \times \bigoplus_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}$. Now consider the map $h : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^\times \to K$ given by $h(a) = \frac{a^*}{a}$ where $a^*$ denotes the conjugate. My understanding is that Hilbert's Theorem 90 implies this map is surjective. Its kernel is $\mathbb{Q}^\times$, so $K$ should be something like $K \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}) \times \bigoplus_{p \text{ prime, } \notin \mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Z}$. [This paper](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-group-of-rational-points-on-the-unit-circle) uses a similar map to obtain the analogous result for $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. It seems like similar reasoning should apply to any UFD.

Now consider a non-UFD, say $D = 10$. Here we have $2 \cdot 5 = \sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{10}$ which at first seems like it might change the structure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})^\times$ compared to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^\times$. However, I think you can throw out $5$ as a generator because you can get it from the other irreducibles as as $(\sqrt{10})^2/2$. It seems like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})^\times$ has a chance of being isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \bigoplus_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ despite not being a UFD. Then applying $h$ should then just kill the factors corresponding to primes in $\mathbb{Q}$, so you might get the same thing for $K$ as with $D = 2$.

Comment: You should get something similar, but using prime ideals instead of primes, and using the ring of integers instead of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ where appropriate. The absolute value of the norm is equal to the norm of the corresponding (principal) ideal, and so is determined by the prime factorization. You would focus on prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ that split (infinitely many) and there are infinitely many combinations leading to principal ideals that will then give you elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$ whose norm has absolute value $1$. I don’t *think* you get any with the property you want.

Comment: Actually, there are a couple (with $D\lt 0$) where the finite factor you get is not $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. You get a factor of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ instead in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ actually has a factor of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $i$. There are only finitely many that have complex roots of unity other than $1$ and $-1$, though. And in the $D\lt 0$ case, the norm is always positive, so you are never hitting a unit with norm $-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In what follows, $L$ is any number field.

We have the following theorem.

**Thm 1.** Let $L$ be a number field, and let $N:L^\times\to \mathbb{Q}^\times$ be the norm map.

Then $\ker(N)\simeq \mathcal{O}_L^\times\cap \ker(N) \times \mathbb{Z}^{(E)}$, for some countable set $E$.

Dirichlet's theorem says that $\mathcal{O}_L^\times $  is finitely generated, thus so is $\mathcal{O}_L^\times\cap \ker(N) $. Note that the torsion part of this last group is the intersection of the torsion group of $\mathcal{O}_L^\times$ , which is the (cyclic) group $\mu_L$ of roots of $1$ contained in $L$,  with $\ker(N)$. Thus:

**Corollary.** $\ker(N)\simeq  \mu_L\cap \ker(N)\times \mathbb{Z}^{(E')},$ where $E$ is countable and $\mu_L$ is the ( cyclic )group of roots of unity contained in $L$.

Thus, **if you stick to subfields of $\mathbb{R}$** (such as real quadratic fields), **you won't get any counterexample**. You need $L$ to contain at least a root of unity of order $n\geq 3$.

**Example.** For all $n\geq 3$, you can take $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Then norms are always positive (because complex conjugation is a non trivial automorphism), and $\mu_L=\langle \mu_n\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ .

Let's now move to the proof of the theorem.

For $z\in L^\times,$ I will denote by $(z)$ the fractional ideal $z\mathcal{O}_L$. Abusing notation, I will also denote by $N(I)$ the norm of any fractional ideal $I$.

If $z$ has norm $1$, so is $(z)$, since $N((z))=\vert N(z)\vert$.

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of principal fractional ideals with norm $1$, and let $f:z\in \ker(N)\mapsto (z)\in\Gamma$.

Then $\Gamma$ is an abelian group, and $f$ is a group morphism.

**Lemma.** $f$ has  kernel $\mathcal{O}_L^\times\cap\ker(N)$.

**Proof.** Assume that $z\in\ker(N)$ satisfies $(z)=z\mathcal{O}_L=\mathcal{O}_L$. Then $z\in\mathcal{O}_L$, and since $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a domain, $z$ must be a unit.
Hence  $z\in \mathcal{O}_L^\times \cap\ker(N)$. Conversely, elements of  $\mathcal{O}_L^\times \cap\ker(N)$ lie in $\ker(f)$.

**Thm 2.** The group $\Gamma$ of principal fractional ideals with norm $1$ is  isomorphic to a subgroup of $ \mathbb{Z}^{(\mathcal{P})}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of nonzero prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Assume thm 2 is proved, and let us prove thm $1$.

By the lemma, we have an exact sequence of abelian groups  $1\to \mathcal{O}_L^\times\cap\ker(N)\to \ker(N)\to Im(f)\to 1$.

By a theorem of Dedekind, if $S$ is any set, any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{(S)}$ is free, and has a basis indexed by a subset of $S$. By Thm2 and this result, $\Gamma$ is then free, and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ for some subset $X$ of $\mathcal{P}$. Now, $Im(f)$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma$, so we can apply the same result again to get that $Im(f)\simeq  \mathbb{Z}^{(E)}$, for some countable set $E$.

Now by the lemma,  we have an exact sequence of abelian groups $1\to \mathcal{O}_L^\times\cap \ker(N)\to \ker(N)\to Im(f)\to 1$. Since $Im(f)$ is free, this sequence splits, and we are done.

We now have to prove Thm 2 above.

If $I$ is a  nonzero fractional ideal, write $I=\displaystyle  \prod_{\mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p}^{r_{\mathfrak{p}}}$, where the $ r_{\mathfrak{p}}'s$ are integers, which are all zero except for a finite number of them. Note that these integers are unique.

Now we have  $N(\mathfrak{p})=p^{f_{\mathfrak{p}}}$, where $p$ is the unique prime number dividing $\mathfrak{p}$ , so $N(I)=1$ if and only if $\sum_{p\mid\mathfrak{p}}f_{\mathfrak{p}}r_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ for all prime $p$.

Now, we have to understand on which conditions on the $ r_{\mathfrak{p}}'s$ such an $I$ is principal.

Fix a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z}\times \cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/d_k\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathcal{C}\ell(L)$ (the class group of
$L$
), and let $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ be the images of $(1,0,\ldots,0), (0,1,0,\ldots, 0),\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1)$ in the class group. Then any element of the class group may be written as $m_1\cdot C_1+\cdots+m_k C_k, m_1,\ldots,m_k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and such a linear combination is zero if and only if $d_i\mid m_i$ for  $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Now for each $\mathfrak{p}$, write $[\mathfrak{p}]=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k a_{i,\mathfrak{p}}\cdot C_i$.
Then $[I]=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k (\sum_{\mathfrak{p}} a_{i,\mathfrak{p}}r_\mathfrak{p})\cdot C_i$ ,and $I$ is principal if and only if $[I]=0$ if and only if $d_i\mid (\sum_{\mathfrak{p}} a_{i,\mathfrak{p}}r_\mathfrak{p})$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Hence, denoting by $\mathcal{P}$ the set of nonzero prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$, we see that $\Gamma$ is canonically isomorphic to the abelian group $$\{(r_\mathfrak{p})_\mathfrak{p}\in\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathcal{P})}\mid \sum_{p\mid\mathfrak{p}}f_{\mathfrak{p}}r_{\mathfrak{p}}=0 \mbox{ for all prime }
 p \mbox{ and } d_i\mid (\sum_{\mathfrak{p}} a_{i,\mathfrak{p}}r_\mathfrak{p})\mbox{ for }i=1,\ldots,k\},$$

which is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathcal{P})}$.